# Hopf fibration extended to bundle over $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, connections, hopf-fibration

Consider the Hopf bundle $h:\mathbb{S}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2$. There is a connection $1$-form $\omega$ oh $h$ which is left $SU(2)$ invariant. In terms of the Euler angles $(\theta,\,\phi,\,\psi)$ this is given by $\omega=d\psi+\cos(\theta)d\phi$. Using $\omega$, we can form a covariant derivative on the associated bundle $\phi:\mathbb{S}^3\times_{U(1)}\mathfrak{u}(1)\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2$. In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02666, the author treats this as a covariant derivative on a bundle over a manifold with topology $\mathbb{C}^2$, such that the curvature is given by $d\omega$.

The only way I can think to extend $\phi$ to a bundle over $\mathbb{C}^2$ is pulling it back via $h$ to a bundle over $\mathbb{S}^3$, then extending radially over $\mathbb{C}^2\cong\mathbb{S}^3\times\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. However, I am not sure how this would be well defined as the $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ component goes to $0$.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could reconcile how to obtain such a bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

Comment: The bundle in question is the tautological line bundle. Its total space  is $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus 0$ and the projection is the natural projection $\mathbb{C^2}\setminus \{0\}\to\mathbb{CP}^1$ that associates  to a nonzero vector the line it determines

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are asking, one thing to point out is that the bundle over $S^2$ _cannot_ extend to a bundle over $\mathbb{C}^2$, since then the Hopf bundle would be trivial—if by 'extend' you mean along some inclusion $S^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts , this makes sense, thanks you. In essence when I say `extend' what I want is the following; I have a connection from $\mathbb{S}^2$ to some some line bundle, this connection has a curvature form $F$ associated to it, I want to somehow get a bundle over $\mathbb{C}^2$ with the same curvature form (which does seem like an inclusion actually).

Comment: If this is in fact what the author does, then it is indeed incorrect. Unless the author is using some kind of generalized covariant derivative, extending it implies extending the bundle, which is not possible here. As you say, it is indeed possible to extend it to the punctured plane but no further.

Comment: @DeaneYang, I may be wrong about the extension. What I am certain of is that he considers the curvature form $F=d\omega$ which should be over $\mathbb{S}^2$, however, he treats it as if it were over $\mathbb{C}^2$ (or $\mathbb{C}P^2\cong\mathbb{C}^2\cup\mathbb{S}^2$). The context is that he is considering a twisted Dirac operator, where the twisting is coming from a scaled version of the connection one form $\omega$.

Comment: Are you sure that form extends continuously to the origin? I'm not.

Comment: I think I may have (somewhat) sorted this out. Although hard to find in the paper I believe the curvature form I mentioned above is scaled by a function depending on $r$ (radial coordinate). The bundle I described above ends up coming through in the limit $r\to\infty$, where $\mathbb{C}^2$ approaches its asymptotic boundary $\mathbb{S}^2$. Although I am still not sure explicitly what the bundle on the bulk $\mathbb{C}^2$ is, I think it is well defined and a proposed "extension" in the way I was describing about is a bit naive. Thanks for t comments, I welcome any more thoughts on the question.